# Cell.Value not working

Tags: vba, excel

MsgBox cannot show value for TestStr1 but The last code `MsgBox Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, 11).Value` can show. Why?

The value returned should be 1.

```
TestStr1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 11).Value
MsgBox (TesStr1)
MsgBox Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, 11).Value
```

The complete code

```
Sub FilterTo1Criteria()

    With Sheets(3)
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    End With

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim TestComp As Integer
    Dim TestStr2 As String
    Dim TestStr1 As Double
    TestStr2 = "Suitable"

    TestStr1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 11).Value
    MsgBox (TesStr1)
    MsgBox Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, 11).Value

    For i = 1 To lastRow
    'TestComp = StrComp(TestStr1, TestStr2, CompareMethod.Text)

        If TestComp = 0 Then

            For j = 1 To 16
                Sheets(5).Cells(i, j) = Sheets(3).Cells(i, j)
            Next j

        End If

    Next i

    End Sub
```

Comment: What is `.Cells(2, 11).Value`?

Comment: Should be a word called "suitable" since I want to compare that latter. This is the original purpose. Then I try something more simple: just a number 1. It still cannot assign the value to the variable TestStr1.

Comment: But MsgBox works. It returns the value 1 and even "suitable" if I change the cell value to suitable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have declared `TestStr1` but your MsgBox wants to display `TesStr1`. Correct the spelling and it will work.

Add `Option Explicit` at the top of each code sheet. I have that in my workbook and it showed me the mistake on first try. Just think of how much time you could have saved. Remember: `Option Explicit`. It means that every variable used in the sheet must be declared, and it is intended to catch types like this one.

Another thing to do is to declare your variable names using caps and smalls but type them using lower case characters only. VBA will correct the case when you finish typing each line of code. If it doesn't there has been a typo.

Comment: So nice of you to thank everyone! :-) I shall definitely be pleased to help you again in the future. But on this site appreciation is required as well as politeness. Select one of the answers as "accepted solution" (as a guide to all who participated or visit this thread in the future). Since you are new you don't have many points to give away, but you can up-mark those answers which also helped anyway.

Answer (score 0):

These two lines of code are referencing two different worksheets.

Sheet**1**:

```
TestStr1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 11).Value
MsgBox (TesStr1)
```

Sheet**2**

```
MsgBox Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, 11).Value
```

My guess would be that the second one works but the first one doesn't because there is probably no value assigned to .Cells(2,11) in Sheet**1** but there probably is a value assigned to same cell in Sheet**2**.

Answer (score 0):

your msgbox it will never show you TestStr1 because you define him as double, change him to string and it will work